# Java Socket HTTP Server gets slow when multiple clients are connected

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket, mjpeg

I'm making a M-JPEG Server in Android, and I have successfully implemented it, but I face a problem:

The first time I connect to it (Using a browser to connect), the stream is good and I get a real-time preview, but opening a new client (like, reloading the page or opening in a new tab), the stream gets slower and slower. Even if I close the previous client, it doesn't improve performance.

I have tried other M-JPEG Android Streamers (like **myMobKit**), it doesn't slow down.

Here is my Server code -

```
public class StreamServer implements Runnable {
    public static Stack<byte[]> bufferStack;
        ...
    public StreamServer(int port) {
        ...
        bufferStack = new Stack<>();
        bufferStack.setSize(100);
    }
    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (isRunning) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new StreamSocket(socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void addBufferToStack(byte[] buffer) {
        bufferStack.push(buffer);
    }
}
```

...And the Socket implementation -

```
public class StreamSocket implements Runnable {

private Stack<byte[]> bufferStack = StreamServer.bufferStack;
    ...
    StreamSocket(Socket socket) throws SocketException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        this.socket.setKeepAlive(false);
    ...
}
@Override
public void run() {
    if (!isStreaming) return;
    PrintStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        // Sent the initial header for M-JPEG.
    ...
        // Start the loop for sending M-JPEGs
        while (isStreaming && !socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                if (bufferStack.empty()) continue;
                byte[] buffer = bufferStack.pop();
                if (buffer == null) continue;
                ... (Some headers needed for M-JPEG streaming. Read it on Wikipedia)
                output.write(buffer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) output.close();
            if (!socket.isClosed() || socket.isConnected()) socket.close();
            isStreaming = false;
            socket = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `addBufferToStack(...)` is called when a new JPEG is made (The camera's preview frame is taken, and processed into a JPG via native code).

I think the Socket Thread is not closed even after client is disconnected, although I am not sure. Please help in this, Thanks!

If any other information/code is needed, please tell, I will edit the question and add it.

**EDIT -**

The `bufferStack` is *not* empty when the server has started. The server is started *after* the camera + a few more things start.

Comment: `new Thread(new StreamSocket(socket));` Have you considered *starting* this thread?

Comment: Sorry, the code here is incomplete, forgot to add `start()` here. Fixing it.

Comment: So this isn't the real code? What does the real code look Iike?

Comment: Updated the code, actually I was testing out ThreadPooling (no performace increase), but when I copied my code here, I changed it to normal Thread

Comment: How can we be sure nothing else significant is missing? And why does your thread spin-loop while the stack is empty?

Comment: I have just cut out the unnecessary parts like code to stop server and http headers. Rest of the code is as-is. The camera starts first to fill the buffer, and then the server starts. Sometimes, the buffer may not be filled so fast (might take some milliseconds to start), so the server loops empty for sometime.

Comment: You catch the IOException indicating the other side closed the connection that is thrown when calling write but you only print it. You should end the thread if it happens.

Comment: Mind that `isConnected` will stay true even if the other end pulls the plug.

Comment: [isConnected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected--): "Note: **Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state**, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed."

Comment: Not sure about `isClosed` - AFAIK it only becomes true when *you* call "close".

Comment: Ok, trying out with some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will keep on looping even if the other side ends the connection:
(note my comments)

```
while (isStreaming && !socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                if (bufferStack.empty()) continue;
                byte[] buffer = bufferStack.pop();
                if (buffer == null) continue;
                ... (Some headers needed for M-JPEG streaming. Read it on Wikipedia)
                output.write(buffer); // <-- will throw Exception if connection is broken
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  // here you should also reset isStreaming
            }
        }
```

By catching the Exception (and not handling it actually), you dismiss the information, that the connection is gone.

Checking `isConnected` as loop condition is superfluent - it will always be true if the socket once has been connected. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected-- :

> Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.

I am currently not 100% sure about the behavior of `isClosed` but I strongly believe it will only turn true when you call `close`, not if an underlying stream throws an IOException.